# How to count position of empty row?

Tags: java, io

I've got flat file like this:

```
[Doc]
Date=14.01.15
Symbol=MUKA
[Content]
[Pos1]
Name=Muka2,0 0,9L ML

[Doc]
Date=14.01.15
Symbol=MUKA
[Content]

[Doc]
Date=14.01.15
Symbol=MUKA
[Content]
[Pos1]
Name=Muka2,0 0,9L ML
```

I want to delete [Doc] statement where content is empty. I'm trying to do this by checking the line have string "[Content]" and then is next line is empty. Then i want to get the number of line (number of row where line is empty after "[Content]") and then add it to list. The [Doc] with empty [Content] part have always 4 lines. So when i get the [Content] position i can substract from it 4 and delete lines between position and position -4.

The file after execution have to look like this:

```
[Doc]
Date=14.01.15
Symbol=MUKA
[Content]
[Pos1]
Name=Muka2,0 0,9L ML

[Doc]
Date=14.01.15
Symbol=MUKA
[Content]
[Pos1]
Name=Muka2,0 0,9L ML
```

I'm trying to do this with function:

```
public void countDesiredLines() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "D:\\Temp.txt"));

    int lines = 0;

    boolean zawiera = false;
    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
        lines++;
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (zawiera == true) {
            zawiera = false;
            if ("".equals(line)) {
                pozycje.add(lines);

            }
        }
        if (line.startsWith("[Content]")) {
            zawiera = true;

        }

        reader.close();

        System.out.println("Wartość pod: " + pozycje.size());
        // for (int i = 0; i < pozycje.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.println("Wartość pod: "+ pozycje.get(i).toString());
        // }
    }
}
```

I've got errors like:

```
Wartość pod: 0
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:115)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:310)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at TextFormatter.countDesiredLines(TextFormatter.java:190)
at TextFormatter.main(TextFormatter.java:51)
```

I'm new in java. If you have any clues or advices please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `readLine()` twice for each iteration, so you will read past the end of the file. Change:

```
while (reader.readLine() != null) {
    lines++;
    String line = reader.readLine();
```

to

```
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines++;
```

Also, you are calling `reader.close()` inside the loop. You will have to move that to outside the loop for your logic to work.

Answer (score 0):

you closed the reader by `reader.close().`  inside the while loop, as a result, in the next loop, IOException occurs.

**you may want to  put it outside the loop**

```
while(){
...
}
reader.close();
```